# Route mqtt and websocket traffic through apache2

Tags: ssl, websocket, apache2, emq

I have a emqx broker setup on Ubuntu EC2.[image]

When I try to connect to emqx through websocket with IP address, it works fine.
[image]
But when I use subdomain, the connection fails. 
My Apache Config is

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName subdomain.example.com
  ServerAlias subdomain.example.com
  ServerAdmin admin@domain.in

  RewriteEngine On
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
  #RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
  RewriteRule ^/mqtt/(.*)           ws://localhost:8083/mqtt/$1 [P,L]

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyRequests Off

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8083/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8083/

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

[image: Apache access logs]
Apache access Logs

[image]
I changed the log level of apache to 'debug' and these are the error logs. Looks like it is trying to find the /mqtt folder.

I have already enabled mode "proxy_wstunnel.load". How can I connect to mqtt and ws using subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `ServerAlias` directive under `ServerName`

Example:

```
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias subdomain.domain.com

Try adding this too

ProxyPass "/" "http://127.0.0.1:8083/mqtt"
ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://127.0.0.1:8083/mqtt"
```

If you're are not sure if the broker is using socket.io, then remove this line:

`#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io`

Comment: You have to restart the server

Comment: Yeah...I did. `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Comment: I just updated the apache conf. Can you check in the question again?

Comment: I setup log level to debug and added the screenshot of error.log file above. Can you check again?

Comment: What's your back end logic that handles the incoming connection?

Comment: Port 8083 is basically running a emqx broker. https://www.emqx.io/

Comment: Do you need to serve any html file? Are you using socket io?

Comment: Nope. Only want the websocket proxy to happen so that I can use domain instead of IP to connect to broker.